# Why does io\open not work in moonscript?

Tags: lua, moonscript

Moonscript uses \ to call methods so can someone explain to me why the code below does not work:

```
> file = io\open("mix.exs", "rb")
[string "tmp"]:1: calling 'open' on bad self (string expected, got table)
```

but when you call it to read the file it does ?

```
> file\read!
"Code.ensure_loaded?(Hex) and Hex.start
```

Answer (score 4):

The `io.open` function expects to get a string as the first argument but `io\open` (like `io:open` in lua itself) is actually passing the `io` table as the first argument. That is it is a method call.

`io\open("file", "mode")`/`io:open("file", "mode")` are syntactic sugar for `io.open(io, "file", "mode")`.

This is why `file\read!` works without an explicit argument because `file` gets passed as the first argument to the `read("file", "format")` function.

Answer (score 0):

> Moonscript uses `\` to call methods

to call *member* methods. as in `a\b c, ...` translates to `a.b(a,c,...)`.

this doesn't work here because `io.open` is a static function (`io.open(what,how)`), not a member (`io.open(self,what,how)`).

you couldn't call `io:open` in Lua either. the only place where `io` functions allow for being called as members is when you want to read/write stdio.

> but when you call it to read the file it does ?

because now it's a *member* method of the file. you're actually still using `io.read` there, but the file object has `io` as a metatable index, therefore allowing you to access the same function via `file.read`, and since `file\read!` translates to `file.read(file)` it's the same thing.

---

so essentially the answer boils down to "because `io:open` doesn't work in Lua".